# NodeJS - Passport Local not getting user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I have a small nodejs express api server, based on the one done by Josh Morony on this post: http://www.joshmorony.com/creating-role-based-authentication-with-passport-in-ionic-2-part-1/

On passport, as several examples show, I try to find the using his email, and then compare passwords. I'm using mongoose.

When I request this route via browser, it works fine. But when i request it throught my ionic 2 app, something goes wrong where I commented "breaks here".

The variable user returns null, although email and password return fine.

route.js

```
requireLogin = passport.authenticate('local', {session: false});    
authRoutes.post('/login', requireLogin, authCtrl.login);
```

passport.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/user');
var config = require('./auth');
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
var ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var localOptions = {
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password' 
};

var localLogin = new LocalStrategy(localOptions, function(email, password, done){    
    //breaks here
    console.log(email)
    User.findOne({  
        email: email
    }, function(err, user){

        console.log(user);

        if(err){
            return done(err);
        }

        if(!user){
            return done(null, false, {error: 'Login failed. Please try again.'});
        }

        user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch){

            if(err){
                return done(err);
            }

            if(!isMatch){
                return done(null, false, {error: 'Login failed. Please try again.'});
            }

            return done(null, user);

        });

    });

});

passport.use(localLogin);
```

Comment: It doesn't even logs the user email? As in the very first line you have written **breaks here**

Comment: It logs the email, but the callback from User.findOne doesn't return neither err, nor user.
If i substitute  

User.findOne({  
    email: email
} 

with

User.findOne({  
    email: "pcezar87..."
}

it works.